# protagonist drills a hole through a mountain

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, reincarnation

I've been trying to search for this manga where the protagonist drills a hole through a mountain using physics and wind magic i think (to connect 2 cities/towns/kingdoms which are separated) in one of the chapters. The protagonist is young, in his teens, and he tries to hide his powers but is found out every time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or online?  Do you remember any details of what the protagonist looks like; hair colour, etc.?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, who was the protagonist trying to hide his powers from?

Comment: [Time Stop Hero](https://myanimelist.net/manga/124797/Jikan_Teishi_Yuusha) fits this description. Young Isekai teen hero. He uses his time-stopping powers to perform seemingly impossible feats because he has unlimited time to do them. This includes hollowing out mountains and building large structures in the blink of an eye

Comment: I'm new here so irdk how to reply directly but i read it within the last 9 months, online and  it was mostly in black and white, don't remember the hair color, the protag was trying to live a "simple' so he was trying to hide his powers from the general public (and probably was a mage in his past life too) he was a child of a noble too if i think bout it

Comment: @user154049 - Can you remember anything that happened, or any other characters that were introduced, near the beginning of the story?

Comment: been trying to think about any more details i can find, nothing has clicked as of yet and i can say that he did it over night and then a messenger came to the king/royalty to inform bout an emergency it being that the mountain had a hole through it oh and he finds a dungeon while he drills through the mountain

Comment: uses a combination of physics and magic to drill through it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[The Greatest Philosopher with Zero Magic.](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/maryoku-zero-de-saikyou-no-daikenja-sore-wa-mahou-de-wa-nai-butsuri-da)*.

> On his deathbed, the Great Philosopher expressed remorse, as he was never able to learn magic. Five hundred years later, **he was reborn as Mazel Loran, the son of a feudal lord**. His family believe him to be a late bloomer in terms of his magic, but also think he’s the next incarnation of the Great Philosopher. But Mazel has a secret that nobody else knows: **while he does not have any magic, he has experience with “physics”**!

The synopsis covers the basic premise; he is reborn in a noble family and uses "physics" with magic. Or instead of magic. I'm honestly not certain what exactly is going on here, because it looks like magic to me.

Early on he tries to hide his immense power, e.g. by not telling anyone that he defeated a giant spider, but other people find out anyway.

The tunnel scene is at the end of Chapter 7. They need to take a detour, and someone comments "if only there was a tunnel". So he creates a giant tunnel with a single motion.

[image: Discussion of the tunnel]

Comment: YES THIS IS THE ONE! THANK YOU SOO MUCH!